# What is the right-most component in this picture?

Tags: identification, colour-coding

[image]

I'm reverse engineering an old RF transmitter circuit and I can't seem to figure out if the right-most component is a 3 band resistor (+/- 20%) or a capacitor (as the label on the board would indicate).

If it is a resistor, my best guess is that it is 380 ohms. Otherwise, I'm completely at a loss.

Comment: The black type  below says "C1"

Comment: Yellow is 4, not 3.

Comment: The bands are, as far as I can tell, brown, grey, orange.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf That's exactly why I thought it would be a capacitor.

Comment: 180nF perhaps??

Comment: Looks like 47 pF to me.  Yellow Violet Black

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Small Disk Capacitor and it's value is 48pF (Yellow, Gray, Black)

More info at:
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/capacitor/cap_5.html

Comment: Highly unusual value and very high too for such a small component. If you read it backwards it’s 47 pF, mush more reasonable.

Comment: It seems you are right @winny. Reading order starts from the thicker band. So I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: Changed from downvote to upvote.

Comment: Do small disc capacitors really come in this shape? I can't find any pictures like it elsewhere. It looks like half a resistor, rather than a disk.

Comment: @Yoshiyahu Very uncommon these days. I would not heasitate to swap to a disc if I would repair it.

Comment: I was hoping for more information on this style of component, but this will have to do. I believe that the correct colors (the picture has poor lighting) are orange (not yellow), gray, and brown, making the capacity 380 pF.

Comment: @Yoshiyahu Only you can tell the color accuracy, but 380 pF is still resonable for such a physically small capacitor, although 47 is far more common than 380. 47 is in the E12 series and 380 requires E24. Your board looks one-layer Pertinax which does not ryme well with E24, but not impossible. Measure it with an LCR meter to tell for sure!

Comment: @winny I thought the E value mismatch was also a tad strange, so I found [a picture](https://sep.yimg.com/ay/yhst-16416632405890/raynor-310mhz-flitestar-r-series-garage-door-opener-remote-45.gif) of the same board online. The color on mine must have faded. Yellow, violet, black seems reasonable. Thanks for all your help.